# Integrating Processing with Chuck with OSC

Tags: networking, processing, chuck, control-p5, oscp5

In processing I made a button "Play Amazing Notes" to send a signal to chuck(for playing notes) with OSC(open sound control),but when I run processing script it shows these error messages.

---

```java
ControlP5 2.2.6 infos, comments, questions at http://www.sojamo.de/libraries/controlP5
play Note
Dec 04, 2016 11:47:23 PM controlP5.ControlBroadcaster printMethodError
SEVERE: An error occured while forwarding a Controller event, please check your code at playNote
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at controlP5.ControlBroadcaster.invokeMethod(Unknown Source)
    at controlP5.ControlBroadcaster.callTarget(Unknown Source)
    at controlP5.ControlBroadcaster.broadcast(Unknown Source)
    at controlP5.Controller.broadcast(Unknown Source)
    at controlP5.Button.setValue(Unknown Source)
    at Kandeze_SendOscMessage.createControls(Kandeze_SendOscMessage.java:51)
    at Kandeze_SendOscMessage.setup(Kandeze_SendOscMessage.java:34)
    at processing.core.PApplet.handleDraw(PApplet.java:2387)
    at processing.opengl.PSurfaceJOGL$DrawListener.display(PSurfaceJOGL.java:871)
    at jogamp.opengl.GLDrawableHelper.displayImpl(GLDrawableHelper.java:692)
    at jogamp.opengl.GLDrawableHelper.display(GLDrawableHelper.java:674)
    at jogamp.opengl.GLAutoDrawableBase$2.run(GLAutoDrawableBase.java:443)
    at jogamp.opengl.GLDrawableHelper.invokeGLImpl(GLDrawableHelper.java:1293)
    at jogamp.opengl.GLDrawableHelper.invokeGL(GLDrawableHelper.java:1147)
    at com.jogamp.newt.opengl.GLWindow.display(GLWindow.java:759)
    at com.jogamp.opengl.util.AWTAnimatorImpl.display(AWTAnimatorImpl.java:81)
    at com.jogamp.opengl.util.AnimatorBase.display(AnimatorBase.java:452)
    at com.jogamp.opengl.util.FPSAnimator$MainTask.run(FPSAnimator.java:178)
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Kandeze_SendOscMessage.playNote(Kandeze_SendOscMessage.java:61)
    ... 24 more
OscP5 0.9.8 infos, comments, questions at http://www.sojamo.de/oscP5


### [2016/12/4 23:47:23] PROCESS @ OscP5 stopped.
### [2016/12/4 23:47:23] PROCESS @ UdpClient.openSocket udp socket initialized.
### [2016/12/4 23:47:24] ERROR @ UdpServer.start()  IOException, couldnt create new DatagramSocket @ port 12000 java.net.BindException: Address already in use: Cannot bind
### [2016/12/4 23:47:24] INFO @ OscP5 is running. you (192.168.0.103) are listening @ port 12000
```

---

My Processing Code looks like this:

```java
import controlP5.*;
import oscP5.*;
import netP5.*;

OscP5 oscP5;
NetAddress dest;
ControlP5 cp5;

void setup(){

  size(200,210,P3D);
  background(0);

  createControls();

  //setUp Osc sending
  oscP5 = new OscP5(this,12000);
  dest = new NetAddress("127.0.0.1",6449);

}

void draw(){
  background(0);
  smooth();
}

void createControls(){
  cp5 = new ControlP5(this);

  cp5.addButton("playNote")
      .setValue(0)
      .setCaptionLabel("Play Amazing Notes")
      .setPosition(10,10)
      .setSize(180,50);

}

void playNote(){
    println("play Note");
    OscMessage msg=new OscMessage("/playNote");
    oscP5.send(msg,dest);
}
```

And the Chuck code is:

```java
Mandolin m=> dac;

OscIn oin;
OscMsg msg;
6448 => oin.port;

"/playNote" => oin.addAddress;

while(true){

    oin =>  now;
    while (oin.recv(msg))

    {
        msg.address @=> string address;
        if(msg.address=="/playNote")
        {
            Math.random2f(48,70) => float note;

            note => Std.mtof => m.freq;

            }

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to initialize OscP5 and NetAddress before creating the control.

```
void setup(){

  size(200,210,P3D);
  background(0);

  //setUp Osc sending
  oscP5 = new OscP5(this,12000);
  dest = new NetAddress("127.0.0.1",6448);

  //create controlls after the OSC setup
  createControls();

}
```

then the error goes away - (the cp5 button event handler has to know the oscP5 object)

Btw. you are using different ports in the processing code (`6449`) and chuck code (`6448`).

Obviously they have to be the same to make it work.

To actually hear the Mandoline playing in the chuck code it needs a noteOn call:

`1.0 => m.noteOn;`